# Can't import Qt for Python in Maya

Tags: qt, maya

I am trying to build a small UI in Maya with QT through Python.

When I use:

```py
from Qt import QtCore
```

In the script editor, it throws the following error:

```
Error: ImportError: file line 2: No module named Qt #
```

I am just starting out to explore this subject. Does this mean Qt isn't installed ? Is it not a part of the default package of Maya 2018 and 2019 ?

Any pointers as to why this may happen will be really helpful.

Comment: Qt for Python is the name of the project but the package is PySide2 so you should use: `from PySide2 import QtCore`

Comment: read the FAQ: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/faq.html#frequently-asked-questions